# How to turn column with lists into dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

I have a dataset:

```
val
[0.5, 0.7,....,0.8]
[0.11, 0.4,....,0.77]
...
[0.99, 0.1,....,0.4]
```

it is pandas.core.series.Series

there are 1000 rows and 200 values in each list. I want to turn it into dataframe with 200 columns and 1000 rows, but when I do `pd.DataFrame(list(df))` it says `NumPy.float64 object is not iterable`. How to fix it?

Comment: Is this dataset a pandas series? or a dataframe?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 it is pandas.core.series.Series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])  # please provide a reproducible example
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({i:col for i,col in s.iteritems()})
```

returns

```
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

You could also use `from_records` with a `transpose`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(s).transpose()
```

Answer (score 2):

With the following data set:

```
data = pd.Series([[0.5, 0.7, 0.8],
[0.11, 0.4, 0.77]])
```

Doing

```
pd.DataFrame(data.values.tolist())
```

Would result in the expected result:

```
       0      1    2
0   0.50    0.7 0.80
1   0.11    0.4 0.77
```

Comment: brings same error for my data

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample of data

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data = pd.core.series.Series([[0.5, 0.7, 0.8],[0.11, 0.4, 0.77]])
>>> data
0      [0.5, 0.7, 0.8]
1    [0.11, 0.4, 0.77]
dtype: object
>>> l = data.values.tolist()
>>> l
[[0.5, 0.7, 0.8], [0.11, 0.4, 0.77]]
>>> pd.DataFrame(l)
      0    1     2
0  0.50  0.7  0.80
1  0.11  0.4  0.77
```

Comment: brings same error for my data